# Syncing user tables - WordPress / MySQL

Tags: mysql, synchronization, registration

I have two WordPress sites that are limited to different user networks (Internal and public). User registrations will fill up on each and therefore, User 7506 may not be the same on each site.

User 7506 may leave a comment on one site and wish to show that comment on the other site with their same user info (e.g., Author name). The post entries would be the same.

Here's a diagram to better demonstrate this problem: http://screencast.com/t/b1NEpAippiA

How would you approach this problem?